# Texture on object doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

#### What I want

I am quite new to *Three.js* and I am trying to **apply a texture** to a loaded object.

#### The problem

I have tried quite a few things and still not sure how to do this. I don't get any errors and the object **loads in but with no texture**.

#### My code

```
var loader6 = new THREE.OBJLoader();

// load a resource
loader6.load(
    // resource URL
    'models/Chair.obj',

    // called when resource is loaded
    function ( object ) {
        object.scale.x = 20;
        object.scale.y = 30;
        object.scale.z = 20;
        object.rotation.y = -0.3;
        object.position.z = -500;
        object.position.x = 30;

        object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                console.log(texture);
                child.material.map =  texture;
            }
        }); 

        var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('models/Chair.mtl');

        object6 = object;
        scene.add( object6 );
    },
```

Any help?

Comment: Thanks for helping me edit the question, first question on stack overflow :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not load `.mtl` file using `TextureLoader`, you have to use `MTLLoader` for that. `MTLLoader` should load the texture. Then you have to set the material to `OBJLoader` using 'setMaterial' function.

Checkout this code -

```
                new THREE.MTLLoader()
                .setPath( 'path to the material folder' )
                .load( 'material_file.mtl', function ( materials ) {

                    materials.preload();

                    new THREE.OBJLoader()
                        .setMaterials( materials )
                        .setPath( 'path to the obj folder' )
                        .load( 'objModel.obj', function ( object ) {

                            object.position.y = - 95;
                            scene.add( object );

                        }, onProgress, onError );

                } );
```